# How to aggregate (min/max etc.) over Django JSONField data?

Tags: json, django, orm

I'm using Django 1.9 with its built-in `JSONField` and Postgres 9.4.
In my model's `attrs` json field I store objects with some values, including numbers. And I need to aggregate over them to find min/max values.
Something like this:

```
Model.objects.aggregate(min=Min('attrs__my_key'))
```

Also, it would be useful to extract specific keys:

```
Model.objects.values_list('attrs__my_key', flat=True)
```

The above queries fail with

> FieldError: "Cannot resolve keyword 'my_key' into field. Join on 'attrs' not permitted."

Is it possible somehow?

Notes:

1. I know how to make a plain Postgres query to do the job, but am searching specifically for an ORM solution to have the ability to filter etc.
2. I suppose this can be done with a (relatively) new query expressions/lookups API, but I haven't studied it yet.

Comment: The answer below is good. Another useful site discussing this can be found [here](http://hatethatcode.com/writing-queries-for-django-models-with-jsonfield.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For those who interested, I've found the solution (or workaround at least).

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

Model.objects.annotate(
    val=RawSQL("((attrs->>%s)::numeric)", (json_field_key,))
).aggregate(min=Min('val')
```

Note that `attrs->>%s` expression will become smth like `attrs->>'width'` after processing (I mean single quotes). So if you hardcode this name you should remember to insert them or you will get error.

/// A little bit offtopic ///

And one more tricky issue not related to django itself but that is needed to be handled somehow. As `attrs` is json field and there're no restrictions on its keys and values you can (depending on you application logic) get some non-numeric values in, for example, `width` key. In this case you will get `DataError` from postgres as a result of executing the above query. NULL values will be ignored meanwhile so it's ok. If you can just catch the error then no problem, you're lucky. In my case I needed to ignore wrong values and the only way here is to write custom postgres function that will supress casting errors.

```
create or replace function safe_cast_to_numeric(text) returns numeric as $$
begin
    return cast($1 as numeric);
exception
    when invalid_text_representation then
        return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

And then use it to cast text to numbers:

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    val=RawSQL("safe_cast_to_numeric(attrs->>%s)", (json_field_key,))
).aggregate(min=Min('val')
```

Thus we get quite solid solution for such a dynamic thing as json.

Comment: The django docs don't really explain how the sql you are writing works. IN the docs, they explicitly name the table you are selecting from. Is there any other documentation which details what you can and cant omit?

Comment: I discovered that if the field names are camel case then escaped double quotes have to be included. I also discovered that ::numeric failed but cast( ... as numeric ) worked. Example ...  _annotations = {
            '_cashTotal':RawSQL("cast(\"payinJson\"->>%s as numeric)",("cashTotal",)),
            '_driverFuel':RawSQL("cast(\"payinJson\"->>%s as numeric)",("driverFuel",)),
            '_fuelAmount':RawSQL("cast(\"payinJson\"->>%s as numeric)",("fuelAmount",))
        }

Answer (score 47):

From django 4.2 There is the new [`KT()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#kt-expressions) expression that makes all of this a bit clearer. It's also secretly just KeyTextTransform [under the hood](https://github.com/django/django/pull/16016/files#diff-57bae26b595ea104733b4f104e47798a93bdb5978d23d541244c960e2e579db7R384-R390)

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    val=KT('json_field__key')
).aggregate(min=Min('val'))
```

From django 1.11 (which isn't out yet, so this might change) you can use [`django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.KeyTextTransform`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L115) instead of `RawSQL` .

In django 1.10 you have to copy/paste [`KeyTransform`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L62) to you own `KeyTextTransform` and replace the `->` operator with `->>` and `#>` with `#>>` so it returns text instead of json objects.

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    val=KeyTextTransform('json_field_key', 'blah__json_field'))
).aggregate(min=Min('val')
```

You can even include `KeyTextTransform`s in `SearchVector`s for full text search

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector(
        KeyTextTransform('jsonb_text_field_key', 'json_field'))
    )
).filter(search='stuff I am searching for')
```

Remember you can also index in jsonb fields, so you should consider that based upon your specific workload.

Comment: Thanks for this. It took me a while to decode how to use this. In my case, the json data is stored in a model field 'jdata' (equivalent to 'attrs' in the question) and the json key is 'createdDate' which is top level.

min_result = Model.objects.annotate(val=KeyTextTransform('createdDate','jdata')).aggregate(min=Min('val'))

Comment: Please note: Since django 3.1 ```KeyTextTransform``` can be imported via ```from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTextTransform```

Comment: Keep in mind that KT in Django 4.2 currently appears to always return the contained values as strings, probably because JSON is not strongly typed, so you can't be sure what the contained value type is.

The Min aggregation in the example works because (I'd guess) you can still apply it lexicographically. But numerical aggregations will not work without an explicit Cast: `val=Cast(KT('json_field__key'), IntegerField())`.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a bit late (several months) but I came across the post while trying to do this. Managed to do it by:

1) using KeyTextTransform to convert the jsonb value to text

2) using Cast to convert it to integer, so that the SUM works:

```
q = myModel.objects.filter(type=9) \
.annotate(numeric_val=Cast(KeyTextTransform(sum_field, 'data'), IntegerField()))  \
.aggregate(Sum('numeric_val'))

print(q)
```

where 'data' is the jsonb property, and 'numeric_val' is the name of the variable I create by annotating.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Correction to my post! Looks like you need to do an extra first step of adding an annotation to cast.

`
q = myModel.objects.filter(type=8) \
.annotate(data_number=KeyTextTransform(sum_field, 'data'))   \
.annotate(numeric_val=Cast('data_number', IntegerField()))     \
.aggregate(Sum('numeric_val'))
`

Comment: You can edit your own answer if you want to make a correction.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do this using a Postgres function

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, FloatField
from django.db.models.expressions import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

text = Func(F(json_field), Value(json_key), function='jsonb_extract_path_text')
floatfield = Cast(text, FloatField())

Model.objects.aggregate(min=Min(floatfield))
```

This is much better than using the `RawQuery` because it doesn't break if you do a more complex query, where Django uses aliases and where there are field name collisions. There is so much going on with the ORM that can bite you with hand written implementations.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution. And if you have nested keys you can repeat the "Value" argument: text = Func(F(json_field), Value(json_key1), Value(json_key2), function='jsonb_extract_path_text')`

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 3.1 the `KeyTextTransform` function on a JSON field works [for all database backends](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/json.py#L287). It maps to the [`->>` operator in Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/).

It can be used to annotate a specific JSON value inside a `JSONField` on the queryset results before you aggregate it. A more clear example how to utilize this:

First we need to annotate the key you want to aggregate. So if you have a Django model with a `JSONField` named `data` and the JSON containing looks like this:

```js
{
    "age": 43,
    "name" "John"
}
```

You would annotate the queryset as following:

```py
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTextTransform

qs = Model.objects.annotate(
    age=Cast(
        KeyTextTransform("age", "data"), models.IntegerField()
    )
```

The `Cast` is needed to stay compatible with all database backend.

Now you can aggregate to your liking:

```py
from django.db.models import Min, Max, Avg, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Round

qs.aggregate(
    min_age=Round(Min("age")),
    max_age=Round(Max("age")),
    avg_age=Cast(Round(Avg("age")), IntegerField()),
)

>>> {'min_age': 25, 'max_age' 82:, 'avg_age': 33}
```

Comment: can you provide an example value for "my_key" and "attrs"?

Comment: @JonathanAplacador If you have a django model with a JSONField which is named `data`, and in this data you have a key `age` it will be:
`age=Cast(KeyTextTransform("age", "data"), models.IntegerField()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no native way to do it.

I worked around like this:

```
my_queryset = Product.objects.all() # Or .filter()...
max_val = max(o.my_json_field.get(my_attrib, '') for o in my_queryset)
```

This is far from being marvelous, since it is done at the Python Level (and not at the SQL level).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import Max, Min

qs = Model.objects.annotate(
    val=Cast('attrs__key', FloatField())
).aggregate(
    min=Min("val"),
    max=Max("val")
)
```

Comment: Might be good to include an explanation of the answer to accompany this code, especially since there are other answers here already. What makes this answer different?