# How do you access a Django JSONField's keys using `django.models.F` or similar method during a query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x

Is it possible to extract a sub-key from a `JSONField` field and annotate the Queryset with its value? I'm trying to extract the value within the query rather than post-processing in the Python code.

Model architecture is:

- Django 1.10
- Model has a django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField`called`data` to store an API response. This example is Twitter.
- Other fields are `profile_id` and `screen_name`. The rest of the data lives within the `data` field so it can be queried ad-hoc.

I thought I'd be able to combine `annotate` and `django.models.F` but I'm getting the following error:

```
> models.TwitterUser.objects.annotate(foll_count=F("data__followers_count"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 914, in annotate
    clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 971, in add_annotation
    summarize=is_summary)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 463, in resolve_expression
    return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1462, in resolve_ref
    self.get_initial_alias(), reuse)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1402, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/Virtualenv/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1370, in names_to_path
    " not permitted." % (names[pos + 1], name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'followers_count' into field. Join on 'data' not permitted.
```

This isn't explicitly documented anywhere so I'm attempting to reverse engineer it using the double underscores used elsewhere in Django. I've separately tried accessing the key as if it was a native Python dict (`F("data")[followers_count"]`) but that didn't work either.

Any direct answers or pointers towards other areas would be appreciated.

Comment: Found someone having a similar issue - http://hatethatcode.com/writing-queries-for-django-models-with-jsonfield.html - so it looks like rawsql might be the only way to go for now until the ORM catches up with the JSONField approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use `F()` at the time of writing so had to fallback to a `RawSQL` call to access the field.

Based on the prior work of [How to aggregate (min/max etc.) over Django JSONField data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325096/how-to-aggregate-min-max-etc-over-django-jsonfield-data) and [José San Gil](http://hatethatcode.com/writing-queries-for-django-models-with-jsonfield.html) on his blog.

```
qs = models.TwitterUser.objects.annotate(followers=RawSQL(
        # The Postgres SQL query to access a JSON object field.
        # `data` is the name of the JSONField in my schema.
        # More: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html
        "((data->%s))",  
        # The parameter to insert into the query and replace '%s'
        # This could be a variable
        # and the query adapted into a reusable universal function.
        ("followers_count",)  # In my example, this is the JSON sub-key I'm after
        )
    )
```

*Note: I've bracketed and indented to hopefully aid comprehension.*

You can also add a `.filter(data__has_key="insert_key_here")` before the `annotate` if you only want to return items that contain the field in question. This is a nice native method for JSON within the ORM and hopefully in time we'll have similar ways of accessing JSON sub-fields directly through the ORM.