# Django annotate specific keys in json fields

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm using Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.5. I have a model (`MyModel`) with a `JSONField` (`django.contrib.postgres.fields`). The JSON value has the same structure in all the objects in the model.

```
{
"key1": int_val_1,
"key2": int_val_2
}
```

I want to order my queryset by a value of a specified key in my `JSONField`. Something like

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(val=F('jsonfield__key1')).order_by('val')
```

This does not work - i get the following error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'key1' into field. Join on 'jsonfield' not permitted.
```

Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to aggregate (min/max etc.) over Django JSONField data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325096/how-to-aggregate-min-max-etc-over-django-jsonfield-data)

Answer (score 28):

for Django >= 1.11, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
MyModel.objects.annotate(val=KeyTextTransform('key1', 'jsonfield')).order_by('val')
```

Comment: How would I use that for nested json fields? For example jsonfield['key1']['key2']

Comment: nested fields with KeyTextTransform is a bit PITA currently - e.g. `MyModel.objects.annotate(val=KeyTextTransform('key1', 'jsonfield')).annotate(val1=KeyTextTransform('key2', 'val'))`.

Comment: so if you have loads of nested JSON fields then the Django query will be nested as hell too: `.annotate(
    n=Cast(
        KeyTextTransform(
            'value',
            KeyTextTransform(
                'field2',
                KeyTextTransform(
                    'field1', 'data'),
            ),
        ),
        output_field=FloatField())`. The logic for `KeyTextTransform` is to traverse the fields in *reverse* order.

Comment: This answer shows an excellent approach for nested fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076146/5153500

Answer (score 4):

An updated answer for this question:

At current time of writing (Django 3.1), you can now order exactly as you had hoped without needing any helper functions:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('jsonfield__key1')
```

Comment: But (v2.2) there seems to be a bug so this does not work in annotations.

Answer (score 0):

JSONExtract is use with mysql
Syntax ('json-field-name', 'json-field-key')
~Q is used for "not equal"

> from django_mysql.models.functions import JSONExtract
> Listing.objects.annotate(weight=JSONExtract('package_dimensions','$.p>ackage_weight')).filter(~Q(weight=0))