# Django annotate count in JSONField with Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-annotate, django-jsonfield

Using Django I have a field which is of type JSONField. I am wanting to get a distinct count on a nested key/value in the json. With a normal field you can just do soemthing like the following

```
model.objects.values('field_name')\
.annotate(total=Count('field_name')).order_by('-total')
```

This does not work for a JSONField.

Example Model

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

Example of data

```
  {
    'name':'sparky',
    'animal':'dog',
    'diet':{
        'breakfast':'biscuits',
        'dinner':'meat',
    }
}
```

Trying

```
Pet.objects.values('data__diet__dinner')\
.annotate(total=Count('data__diet__dinner')).order_by('-total')
```

Exception of

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What is the correct way to execute this?

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325096/how-to-aggregate-min-max-etc-over-django-jsonfield-data ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [jsonb_extract_path_text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) via a [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) object as an alternative to the field transform:

```py
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db.models.expressions import F, Func, Value

pets = (
    Pet.objects.annotate(
        dinner=Func(
            F("data"),
            Value("diet"),
            Value("dinner"),
            function="jsonb_extract_path_text",
        )
    )
    .values("dinner")
    .annotate(total=Count("dinner"))
)
```

The reason why the field transform `data__diet__dinner` fails is an error within Django when you go deeper than just one level into the json structure *and* use `GROUP BY` in the SQL. The first level (`name`, `animal`, `diet`) should work fine.

The reason seems to be that for nested transforms, Django changes the SQL syntax used, switching from a single value to a list to specify the path into the json structure.

This is the syntax used for non-nested json transforms (= first level):

```
"appname_pet"."data" -> 'diet'
```

And this is the syntax used for nested transforms (deeper than first level):

```
"appname_pet"."data" #> ARRAY['diet', 'dinner']
```

While constructing the query, Django chokes on that list while working out the required `GROUP BY` clauses. This does not seem to be an inevitable restriction; the support for transforms is quite new, and this is possibly one of the kinks that haven't been worked out yet. So if you open a [Django ticket](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions), this might just work a few versions down the line.