# Django: using F() expressions on JSONField?

Tags: python, django

I have the model

```
class Product(Model):
    properties = JSONField()
```

When querying

```
Product.objects.values('properties__color')
```

i'm getting the correct result

> SELECT product.properties->color FROM product

However, when I'm doing what I thought to be equivalent

```
Product.objects.values(color=F('properties__color'))
```

the query that's executed is completely different

> SELECT product.properties AS color FROM product

Is this a bug of django's JSONField, or have I misunderstood `F()` expressions?

Comment: seems like a bug, which django version you are on?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali: version 2.2

Answer (score 7):

You can use a plain `values('fieldname__lookup')` because `values()` supports lookups since v2.1:

```
Product.objects.values('properties__color')
```

`F` expressions however do not support lookups; in fact they silently discard them, as evidenced by your example.

When using `JSONField` transforms, watch out for a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058554/django-annotate-count-in-jsonfield-with-postgres) when the field you're looking for is nested more than one level deep. In the linked question you will also find a solution for using a named annotation if a plain `values()` is not sufficient.