# Get mean value for price in dict (Django JSONField)

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-jsonfield

I need to extract some products from orders with the same SKU number.

```
orders=Order.objects.filter(products__contains=[{"sku":"002-2-1"}])

for e in orders:
    print(e.products)

>>> [{'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '366.00'}, {'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '300.00'}] # 2 products in 1 order
>>> [{'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '400.00'}]  # 1 product in the order
```

I need to find the mean value of "price"

I tried to get a one list with dicts:

```
a = sum(list(orders.values_list("products", flat=True)), [])

[{'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '366.00'}, {'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '300.00'}, {'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '400.00'}]
```

How can I find the mean value of price?

`[mean(e.get("price")) for e in a]`

May be there is a better way to find it via F?

Comment: Could you please add the `Order` model to displayed code? I'd like to see how you defined the `Order.products`.

Comment: @ Tarquinius, products in the Order model ```products = models.JSONField()```

Comment: I found a ```mean(Decimal(d['price']) for d in sum(list(orders.values_list("products", flat=True)), []))  ```, but I think it's too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try it but please give this a try:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

order_qs = Order.objects.filter(products__contains=[{"sku":"002-2-1"}])
print(order_qs.aggregate(Avg("products__price")))
```

Interesting resources: 
[Key, index, and path transforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#key-index-and-path-transforms) - how to "deal" with jsonfield lookups 
[`Avg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#avg) - the function you want to aggregate your queryset with to get the mean value 
[Conditional Aggregating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) - general "how-to" how to aggregate with functions like `Count` or mentioned `Avg`

**Even though you did not ask** for a potentially better way I want to say: "Why are you using a `JSONField`?". In my eyes creating another model called `Product` and link it via a `ForeignKey` to `Order` makes much more sense. It also enables all the cool django features like aggregating, annotating and so much more. Especially if the scheme of the `JSONField` is always the same... what's the point in not creating a further model?

I can guarantee you that with a dedicated `Product` model the provided solution is going to work. With a `JSONField` I am not 100% sure - let me know!

Comment: thank you, but it don't work, because "product' is a list [{'sku': 002-2-1, 'price': '400.00'}]. So, each products field is a list with one dict. The method that works, I wrote above, but I don't like it. I can try ```queryset.aggregate(Avg("products__0__price"))``` but I get an error ```TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float```.  I agree that we need to get rid of JSONField. But I can't do that right now.

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34325096/18018869) is helpful for you? Instead of min/max you would want to go for `Avg`

Comment: Hey, Irina_Xena. I see you accepted the answer. Do I need to edit my answer to make it 100% correct? I am asking because you at first said it is not working out for you.

Comment: anyway, your solution works if the structure of products was a dict.